# Get the windows user logged on a machine using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a SQL Agent job that creates a list of database users to the managers, monthly.
For SQL Authenticated Users, they want to know the username of the person/process logged on the machine from which SQL database is being hit. I know that I can get the host_name using sys.dm_exec_sessions. Would anyone happen to have a powershell script to get the user/process of that host, or any other idea on how this can be achieved?

Comment: `((gwmi win32_process -filter "processid=14892").GetOwner()).User`. But you'll probably need remoting to get that to work on the machine itself (`Invoke-Command`) -- you can use `-comp <host>` to do the WMI query remotely, but even with remote WMI enabled I'm pretty sure retrieving the user this way won't work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no link between a SQL login and an NT user. Backtracking with hostname is your best bet.

Comment: I agree, I can get host_name using sys.dm_exec_sessions in SQL Server. Is there a script in handy that I could use to get the NT_User from host name?

Comment: @Jay `Get-WmiObject –ComputerName <machine name> –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName`

Answer (score 0):

Below query will fetch you the Username and the machine details:-

SELECT HOST_NAME() AS HostName, SUSER_NAME() LoggedInUser

Comment: This gives the host name of the current machine and the current user. I need to find out the NT_Username of the person who was logged on at a particular time on a particular machine?